# ROC curve end point confusion

Tags: machine-learning, python, roc, numpy

Here is the code and output, I think from the output, it mean when fpr is 0, tpr is 0, this is correct as the prediction results marks everything to be 0.

But the output also said, when fpr is 1, tpr is also 1. I think it is not correct, since the predictor never predict something to be positive (label to be `1`), so how could the fpr (= # of correct prediction of 1/total # of 1) and tpr (= # of prediction of 1 / total # of 0) both to be 1? Wondering if it is a routine in ROC, we have to draw something as final point (fpr, tpr) as (1, 1)?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
pred = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred)
print fpr
print tpr
print thresholds
print metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```

**Output**,

```
[ 0.  1.]
[ 0.  1.]
[1 0]
0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPR = Correct 1's / (Total number of 1's)

FPR = Incorrect 0's / Total number of 0's

If you have 50 1's and 50 0's and you predicted all as 1's, then:

TPR = 50/50 = 1

FPR = 50/50 = 1

EDIT: This is response to the "predictor never made a prediction of label =1". The issue here is in understanding how the ROC is developed. Each point on the ROC is effectively based on modifying your threshold to calculate what happens to TPR and FPR under the new threshold.

For example, assume an actual set of labels: (0,0,1,1,1)

And predicted probabilities were: (0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7) with no explicit predictions as 1.

Now if you set your threshold as 0.2, then your output classes would be: (0,0,1,1,1) in which case you get TPR=1, FPR =0

Now if you modify your threshold to 0.1 then your output classes would be: (0,1,1,1,1) in which case you get TPR=1, FPR = 0.5

finally if you used threshold of 0 then your output classes would be: (1,1,1,1,1) in which case you get TPR=1, FPR=1

The ROC then, is the line which joins all possible values of TPR, FPR for all possible values of threshold.

Comment: Thanks Arun, vote up for your answer. But for my example, I never predict anything to be positive `1`, I am confused about `fpr` and `tpr`, which the last element means when `fpr` is 1, `tpr` is also 1, any thoughts?

Comment: I think the trouble is your correct definition of fpr. It is not what you wrote: "fpr (= # of correct prediction of 1/total # of 1)"

Comment: Have edited my answer to give you a longer explanation.

Comment: Thanks Arun for the details, and for your example, I 100% agree. Vote up for your both posts. Actually my question is more about my specific example, posted in my original post. Could you explain in the example I posted, (where `y` is the label, `pred` is the predicted results), how could `tpr` to be 1 somewhere since I never predict anything to be positive? And how could `fpr` to be 1 somewhere since I never predict anything to be positive?

Comment: When your threshold is 0, all your predicted classes (not probabilities) will be 1. In this case tpr=fpr=1

Comment: In your example, pred = predicted probabilities, not classes. I think that should make it clear.

Comment: Thanks Arun, for your comments, "When your threshold is 0, all your predicted classes (not probabilities) will be 1", where do you see in my example, you can conclude when threshold is 0, predicted class will be 1?The predicted score is always 0 (where list `pred` represents for), do you mean when select threshold to be 0, all predicted scores are >= 0 (since predicted 0 >= threshold 0), which means everything will be labelled as 1?

Comment: When you call the metrics.roc function, what it does for you is apply the thresholds for you. The array "pred" in your code is treated as probabilities, not as classes. So when threshold is 0, then all predictions are 1. Hence tpr=fpr=1

Comment: Thanks Arun to make it all clear, mark your reply as answer.